# Sugar ORM: Insert data into table having foriegn key

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I use [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) in my android App. I have the data structure as

```
public class Attendance extends SugarRecord<Attendance> {

Date logDateTime;
String Flag;
Shift shift;
...
```

and

```
public class Shift extends SugarRecord<Shift> {

String shiftName;
Date startTime, EndTime;
...
```

I have data in Shift table but the [documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html#why) doesn't help much in explaining how I can create a new row in Attendance table.

Can anyone someone provide a sample code on how to create a entry in Attendance table with a reference to the Shift table.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a solution..

```
        List<Shift> st1 = Shift.listAll(Shift.class);

     //should figure out the best way to link the reference key and array counter. 
     // If the PK of the master table is identity //or at least an integer
//this can be worked out easily.

selectedShift = st1.get(0);
    Attendance attendance = new Attendance();

    attendance.setShift(selectedShift);
    attendance.setFlag("E");
    attendance.setLogDateTime(new Date());
    attendance.save();
```

thanks.